# vertex paint not very efficient in python, blender stops working

Tags: python, vertex-groups, vertex-colors, vertex-paint, vertex-paint-mode

Imagine you have the following situation: you want to color the vertices relative to a certain vertex group x in red. I used the following function the problem is that it is not very efficient in fact blender stops working immediately, I'm working on a mesh with about 230,000 vertices and 500,000 faces (I just started developing addons blender and I still have a long way to go).
PS. This operation will not be repeated once but many more depending on how many vertex groups I need to color

```
            name_vertex_group = "myVG"
            name_mesh = "myMesh"
            
            mesh = bpy.data.objects[name_mesh].data
            vertex_group = bpy.data.objects[name_mesh].vertex_groups[name_vertex_group].index
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = "VERTEX_PAINT")

            index_vertex = []   
            vs = [vertex for vertex in mesh.vertices if(vertex.groups)]
            for vertex in vs:
                for vgroup in vertex.groups:
                    if(vgroup.group==vertex_group):
                        index_vertex.append(vertex.index)
                        break

            for face in mesh.polygons:
                for vert in index_vertex:
                    for loop_index in face.loop_indices:
                        loop_vert_index = mesh.loops[loop_index].vertex_index
                        if vert == loop_vert_index:
                            mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color = [255, 0, 0, 1]
                            break
            
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = "EDIT")
```

Answer (score 2):

Am I right to guess you're running this script from Edit Mode? If that's the case, you can use **Bmesh** to loop through the mesh and set the colors.

The execution time will vary wildly depending on your computer build, but this method has been taking 1-2s to process a mesh with 1.5 million faces, as opposed to 15 seconds when using an approach altering `data` directly like yours.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from time import time


obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

# Vertex group index => vertex color
vgroup_colors = {
    obj.vertex_groups['Test_VGroup'].index: (0, 0, 1, 0),  # BLUE
    obj.vertex_groups['Test_VGroup2'].index: (1, 0, 0, 1),  # RED
}

# Extract group indexes for later usage
target_vertex_groups = vgroup_colors.keys()

# Destination vertex color layers
vcolor_layers = {
    obj.vertex_groups['Test_VGroup'].index: bm.loops.layers.color['Col'],
    obj.vertex_groups['Test_VGroup2'].index: bm.loops.layers.color['Col2'],
}

# Get vertex group weight layers
dl = bm.verts.layers.deform.verify()

start = time()
for vertex in bm.verts:
    
    # Only loop through vertex groups when vertex belongs to any
    if len(vertex[dl]):

        # Return keys (vertex group indexes) of groups in which this vertex has weight over 0
        in_vgroups = [vgroup_index for vgroup_index, weight in vertex[dl].items() if (weight)]
        
        # Extract indexes of groups of interest from this list
        in_target_vgroups = set(target_vertex_groups).intersection(in_vgroups)
        
        
        # For each face corner this vertex is part of
        for face_corner in vertex.link_loops:
        
            # Set colors for found vertex groups
            for vgroup_idx in in_target_vgroups:
                face_corner[vcolor_layers[vgroup_idx]] = vgroup_colors[vgroup_idx]

end = time()
print("%ss elapsed" % (end-start))

# Update viewport
obj.data.update()
```

Comment: hi your solution is very good but I still have a problem.
If for example I have to color 1 or 2 vertex groups then your solution is perfect, but if I am in the bad case where I have to color a hundred vertex groups then blender takes longer to run your script.
To give you an idea, the largest vertex group has 42000 vertices inside it, is there a more efficient solution in this case?